# can't provisioning table in wcf

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

i'm trying to create wcf service to process all syncronize, i've tried to privisioning table and i get error like

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

it never happens before when i use SQL Server 2005,but when i replace it to SQL Server 2008, this error pops up :(
please someone help me

here my code in wcf

```
  public string DefiningScopeAndProvisioningServer(string conSQL, string tableName, string type)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] splitString = null;
            splitString = tableName.Split('|');

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conSQL);
            foreach (string _tableName in splitString)
            {


                DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(_tableName + "_Scope");
                //definisikan scope table
                DbSyncTableDescription tabDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(_tableName, con);
                //tambahkan table ke scope definisi
                scopeDesc.Tables.Add(tabDesc);
                switch (type)
                {
                    case "Provisioning":
                        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning srvProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(con, scopeDesc);
                        srvProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
                        //SyncTracer.Verbose("")
                        srvProvision.Apply();
                        break;
                    case "Deprovisioning":
                        SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning srvDeProvision = new SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning(con);
                        srvDeProvision.DeprovisionScope(_tableName + "_Scope");
                        srvDeProvision.DeprovisionStore();
                        break;
                }



            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (SyncException ex)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //sb.Append("\n Error Number : " + ex.ErrorNumber.ToString());
            sb.Append("\n Message : " + ex.Message);
            sb.Append("\n Stack Trace :" + ex.StackTrace);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you want to IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults in your configuration of the service? If you set `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true than, perhaps, we will understand what is going on more precisely.

Comment: hi Engineer Spock, it works i can see now what wrong, and the problem is 'Requested value 'geography' was not found' , in my table there field with type data geography. is that type data can't be provisioning???. thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of the businesss logic in your program. I only wanted to say that it's very helpful during debugging to turn on the  `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults`